# Non-greedy match does not work

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like this

```
<tag1>
    <tag1>
        any text
    </tag1>
    text
</tag1>
```

and I want to find a `<tag1>`, that contains shortest text in this string.

I used the following regex `<tag1>.*?</tag1>`, but instead of `<tag1>any text</tag1>` i got `<tag1> <tag1>any text</tag1>`. Here is the [example](http://regexr.com?3803n).

Why it doesn't works and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `(.*)(<tag1>.*?</tag1>)` which matches the last inmost occurrence, but in general, it's not a good idea to use regular expressions for this purpose (they're not powerful enough to work with "bracketing")

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @IdanArye some people just won't learn...

Comment: `(.*)(<tag1>.*?</tag1>)` doesn't works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not working, because it will start matching at the first `<tag1>` and then match as least as possible, so ending at the first `</tag1>`, resulting in "`<tag1> <tag1>any text</tag1>`".

You can avoid matching tags by using a negated [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

```
<tag1>[^<>]*</tag1>
```

[See it on Regexr](http://regexr.com?38046).

The other possibility is to use a negated [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and match the next character only, if it is not the tag.

```
(<tag1>)((?!\1).)*?</tag1>
```

[See it on Regexr](http://regexr.com?38049)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simple code to solve your specific problem :

```
<tag1>[^<]*</tag1>
```

Comment: What about ```<tag1><tag2/></tag1>``` or escaped gt like ```<tag1><![CDATA[<]]></tag>```

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj 1. Hope it never happens. 2. Stop attempting with regex. In that order :)

Answer (score 0):

I would be able to help you if those tags were not nested inside themselves (the same tag).

It is generally a bad idea to do this type of thing with regex. You should get a proper parser to fit your requirements.